# The python program can print the entire window on a printer on Thonny Python IDE, but not on LXTerminal

Tags: python, tkinter

I develop Python3 program on Thonny Python IDE on Raspberry Pi 3B+. 
I use Tkinter for the GUI.

Now, I want to write a program that prints the entire window on a printer by pressing a button on the window.
 I was already successful on Thonny Python IDE.
 But, when it works on LXTerminal, an an error message appears, after the button is pressed. 
 I want it work correctly on LXTerminal.

The program and the error message are as follow.
 What should I do now?

Error message:

```
giblib error: Saving to file .screenshot2020-0224_16-01-14-611084.png failed

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "./Projects/tk.py", line 18, in printer
img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(400,200,800,500))
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 476, in 
_screenshot_linux
im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2634, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.screenshot2020-0224_16-01-14-611084.png'
```

the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding: utf8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import subprocess
from PIL import Image
import io
import pyautogui




def printer():
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(400,200,800,500))

    img.save(buf, 'PNG')

    p = subprocess.Popen('lp', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(buf.getvalue())

    p.stdin.close()
    buf.close()



root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-type','splash')
root.geometry("400x300")

button = tk.Button(root,text="exit",command=sys.exit)
button.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(root,text="print",command=printer)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you have `scrot` installed in your Linux?

Comment: I installed scrot. But, the result is same.

Comment: Try `img = pyautogui.screenshot('/tmp/screenshot.png', region=(400,200,800,500))` and see whether `/tmp/screenshot.png` is created.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My problem resolved. I can printed correctly. I found 'screenshot.png' in 'tmp'.